# jQuery - Sliding background color without using images

Tags: jquery, css, hover, slide

So, yeah, as the titles says - is there a way to change the background color (on hover) of a navigation menu item using sliding animation? And **without using images**?

It's easy to do fading animation using jQuery or CSS3, but is there a way for the hover color to slide from **left to right** for example?

*I know there are a lot of threads on this, but they all include using images.*

Comment: Like this: http://jqueryui.com/animate/#default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#"><span>aosgibmoa bnocibnas</span></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    padding:2px 5px;
}
a>span{
    position:relative;
}

a::before{
    content:'';
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:0%;
    -webkit-transition:width .3s ease-out;
}
a:hover::before{
    width:100%;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nsfxE/

---

Alternative using gradient: (thanks Bojangles)

**CSS:**

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(50%,red), color-stop(50.001%,green));
    background-size:200% 100%;
    background-position:0 0;
    -webkit-transition:background-position .3s ease-out;
}

a:hover{
    background-position:-100% 0;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nsfxE/1/

Comment: +1 very nice. My first thought was to use a CSS gradient with a 0px wide stop to get a change in colour, but this is better

Comment: @Bojangles Wow, using a gradient is actually a pretty awesome idea as well. Updated my answer with a gradient solution. Thanks :) (note: my example(s) as they are now will obviously only work on webkit)